# How to read decimal logical type into spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro, spark-avro

I have an Avro file containing a decimal logicalType as follow:

```
"type":["null",{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":19,"scale":2}]
```

when I try to read the file with scala spark library the df schema is

```
MyField: binary (nullable = true)
```

How can I convert it into a decimal type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify schema in read operation:

```
val schema = new StructType()
    .add(StructField("MyField", BooleanType))
```

or you can cast column

```
val binToInt: String => Integer = Integer.ParseInt(_, 2);
val binToIntegerUdf = udf(binToInt);

df.withColumn("Myfield", binToIntegerUdf(col("MyField").cast("string")))
```

Comment: the cast solution raise the following error: cannot resolve 'CAST(`MyField` AS DECIMAL(10,0))' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast binary to decimal(10,0);

Comment: Updated. You can write your own function to do it and save it as udf.

Comment: This solution does not work.
A `binary` cannot be `cast`ed into `decimal`. 
Casting it into `string` converts the underlying `Array[Byte]` to `String`. It does not return the string representation of the decimal